# how to create VM with Json arm template using define VHD (or disk,snapshot)?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-deployment, vhd, azure-rm-template

The question in the title: "how to create VM with Json arm template using define VHD (or disk,snapshot) in azure?" Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/ps-template

Comment: Have you tried Googling that?

Comment: yes,but i cant find the answer( give me link please if its not hard for you

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean with "using define template"? It will be helpful If you can provide more details.

Comment: Im sorry. This is right question

Comment: If you want to create the vm from a specific VHD file, you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-new-or-existing-vnet/azuredeploy.json).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I would add the answer for others who look for this as you. You can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the vm from VHD file through the template. The steps are that you can upload the VHD file to an Azure storage account and create a managed disk from the VHD file. Then attach it to the VM.

Create the managed disk from the VHD file:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('diskName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "creationData": {
          "createOption": "Import",
          "sourceUri": "[parameters('osDiskVhdUri')]"
        },
        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]"
      }
    }
```

Attach the managed disk to the VM:

```
"storageProfile": {
          "osDisk": {
            "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
            "createOption": "Attach",
            "managedDisk": {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', variables('diskName'))]"
            }
          }
        }
```

You can get the whole template [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-new-or-existing-vnet/azuredeploy.json).